# Compress the values in a double array (not memory compression)

Tags: java, arrays

I'm trying to figure out how to compress an `array` of `doubles`, and when I have googled this, it only seems to come up with compressing the size of an array in memory.

I want to compress the actual values of the array, so basically the length of the array is reduced and the range of values stays the same.

What I mean is kind of hard to explain, here is an example:

an array with the values `{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8}`
compressed by a factor of 2 will become

```
double[] {0.0, 2.0, 4.0, 8.0}
```

and

compressed by a factor 0f 0.5 will become

```
double[] {0.5, 1.0, 1.5, 2.0, 2.5, 3.0, 3.5, 4.0, 4.5, 5.0, 5.5, 6.0, 6.5, 7.0, 7.5, 8.0}
```

Sorry if this is a duplicate, I did research and found nothing on this.

Thanks.

Comment: what is the result of compressed by a factor of 3? and what for 10

Comment: You should give a clear mathematical definition of your problem, as it is not clear what you are trying to accomplish in general.

Comment: You said _"no values are deleted"_, but in your example, you have deleted few values in compression by factor 2?

Comment: This is not compression, it looks like you are taking a specific number of equidistant points in a certain range. It could be interpolation? You have to describe it more detailed.

Comment: oh, sorry, I wasnt specific. By "no values are deleted" I meant that the values at the end of the array aren't just cut off when reducing the size. The values in the array are changed to fit the new size. So in the example above, the array keeps its range of 1 to 8.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to make a method that does this in java, i have a suggestion...

```
double[] compressDoubleArray(double[] orgArray, double compFactor){
    Arrays.sort(orgArray);
    double maxValue = orgArray[orgArray.length - 1];
    double minValue = orgArray[0];
    int i = 0;
    double[] newArray = new double[orgArray.length/compFactor];
    while(minValue <= maxValue){
        newArray[i] = minValue;
        minValue += compFactor;
        i++;
    }
    return newArray;
}
```

bare in mind that this is just a bit code i threw together and you may have to do some work on it to get the desired effect.

Comment: Awesome this works for the most part. Thanks. It's a little weird in the fact that when compressing by 0.5 for example, the last value is set to 0.0. But I'll figure that out.